# Generalized likelihood ratio to Probability estimate

Tags: maximum-likelihood-estimation

I implemented a generalized likelihood ratio test (GLRT) detector/identifier.
The result of the identification step results in a score for each of the objects to be identified in an ordered list. The ratio values are log of a ratio number.

Is there a way to compute an estimate of the probability/confidence of similarity in that estimate ?

Comment: well, the values should be monotonous with confidence. The conversion from log-likelihoods (or ratios thereof) to likelihoods depends on the distribition of error.

Comment: Can you write down the closed-form expression of the GLRT?